# First module HelloWorld in Magento 2.0 doesn't work

Tags: module, magento2, error, command-line

- CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
- WHM version 11.52.1.3 (Root access)
- Cpanel Apache 2.4.16
- PHP 5.5.30
- MySQL 5.6
- Magento-CE-2.0.0+Samples.* Extracted (.tar.bz2) on my server ,and ran
  the Setup Wizard.

I did this example 
http://cedcommerce.com/blog/magento2/hello-world-module/

---

**public_html/app/code/Ced/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml**

```
<config>     
      <module name="Ced_HelloWorld" schema_version="2.0.0" setup_version="0.0.1">
      </module>
</config>
```

I also try

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ced_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

---

**public_html/app/code/Ced/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi: ="../../../../../ ../lib/internal/
Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Ced_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I also try

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi: ="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Ced_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

---

I also add

**public_html/app/etc/config.php**

```
 ...
      'Magento_Wishlist' => 1,
        'Magento_WishlistSampleData' => 1,
        'Ced_HelloWorld' => 1,
      ),
```

---

I also run this commands line

> php-cli bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php-cli -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content
>   Ced_HelloWorld

->Unknown module(s): 'Ced_HelloWorld'

> php-cli bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php-cli bin/magento setup:di:compile

I also flush the cache of the admin panel.

---

I checked and pdo_mysql extension is installed
Permission directories 755 files and 644 for all Magento files

---

In browser magentodir/helloworld

*Whoops, our bad...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.*

Comment: @ibnab u are right .. i clean  cache , delete var/dir and run setup:upgrade .. but now gave me other message Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Failed to parse QName 'xsi:' in Entity, line: 2 in /home/magentoadm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 365
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'DOMDocument::lo...', '/home/magentoad...', 365, Array)

Answer (score 2):

Follow bellow steps

**Step : 1** (module.xml)
app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ccc_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step : 2** (routes.xml)
app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
        <module name="Ccc_HelloWorld" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

**Step : 3** (registration.php)
app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Ccc_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step : 4** (Index.php)
app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php 
namespace Ccc\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,PageFactory $resultPageFactory)     
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Hello World'));
        return $resultPage;        
    }
}
```

**Step : 5** (HelloWorld.php)
app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\HelloWorld\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {  
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**Step : 6** (helloworld_index_index.xml)
app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Ccc\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step : 7** (helloworld.phtml)
app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld.phtml

```
<?php 
echo 'Successful! This is a simple module in Magento 2.0';
?>
```

**Step : 8** (rerun magento setup - this will re-generate app/etc/config.php & enable the module)

> php-cli bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> I also flush the cache of the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

in M2 release you need create registration.php in root of your module app/code/Ced/HelloWorld/registration.php:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Ced_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should validate all xml issues first 

See more [sample-module-here](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-newpage)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you also try our recently updated [sample modules](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples). They're all set up with `registration.php` and everything else you need.